# How to prevent swagger from showing allowed methods GET?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0, http-method

I realized that when I try to access one of the paths defined in my swagger 2.0 with an incorrect method (ie. GET instead of POST), I receive the following message:

{"message":"Route defined in Swagger specification (/movie) but there is no defined get operation.","allowedMethods":["POST"]}

I am getting the above error. I am using nodeJs server and What i will add into the nodejs file.. Anyone help me how to solve this error.

Comment: Post your server and controller configuration.

Comment: @vishnupriya please put your content in your question section, you can edit your question, as provided link below your question. and please remove your answer.